# Waiting for the joint_trajectory_action server

Tags: ros, ros-groovy, joint-trajectory-action, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey Guys, I am trying to do some demos on a real Pr2, but I cant make it move it arms.

At first, I tried http://wiki.ros.org/pr2_interactive_manipulation
And there occurs no error, robot comes up and on my desktop, rviz shows up all Ok, but then when I try to move its arms to the front or so it doesnt move.

So I tried something even more basic: pr2_props
On Robot
roslaunch pr2_props pr2_props.launch
And on the desktop
rosrun pr2_props hug

But I keep getting this message on a loop:

```
[ INFO] [1413233159.293564120]: Waiting for the joint_trajectory_action server
[ INFO] [1413233164.293692161]: Waiting for the joint_trajectory_action server
[ INFO] [1413233169.293832716]: Waiting for the joint_trajectory_action server
[ INFO] [1413233174.293930410]: Waiting for the joint_trajectory_action server
```

Any ideas what it could be?

```
@pr1023:~$ rosrun pr2_controller_manager pr2_controller_manager list
base_controller ( running )
base_odometry ( running )
head_camera_trigger ( running )
head_traj_controller ( running )
l_arm_controller ( running )
l_forearm_cam_trigger ( running )
l_gripper_controller ( running )
laser_tilt_controller ( running )
projector_controller ( running )
projector_trigger ( running )
prosilica_inhibit_projector_controller ( running )
r_arm_controller ( running )
r_forearm_cam_trigger ( running )
r_gripper_controller ( running )
torso_controller ( running )
```

these are my controllers. is it how it is supposed to be or am I missing something?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194887/waiting-for-the-joint_trajectory_action-server/) by [Fred Eduardo](https://answers.ros.org/users/20246/fred-eduardo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2014-10-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-14**:
This could be a network problem. Does it work if you run everything on the robot?

**Comment by [Fred Eduardo](https://answers.ros.org/users/20246/fred-eduardo/) on 2014-10-15**:
Well, tuckarms work just fine. Could this be a network problem just for the controllers? Cause, on the desktop, using pr2_interactive_manipulation, Rviz shows correct information/states of the robot, so it receives data on the network. When I click 'move right arm', however, then it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your PR2 doesn't seem to be running the expected controllers. The instructions can either be out of date (note that Groovy is already EOL'ed), or your PR2 bringup logic does not coincide with the expectations of the demo instructions. You can query the list of running and stopped controllers by running

`rosservice call /pr2_controller_manager/list_controllers`

If the expected controllers are there, but stopped, you should just start them, otherwise you might have to load their configuration to the param server, load the controllers, and then start them.

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2014-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-14**:
On the PR2, you get much better output by using the [pr2_controller_manager](http://wiki.ros.org/pr2_controller_manager): `rosrun pr2_controller_manager pr2_controller_manager list`

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's quite possible that topics only work in one direction (from the robot to your desktop, but not back).

For more information, go watch my ROSCon talk from 2013: https://vimeo.com/67806888

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yeah! after seeing your video I figured it out. My desktop could reach the Pr2 (Of course), but c1 could not reach my desktop. So I just added it to the hosts file and now everything works. Thanks a lot man! awesome talk!

---

Originally posted by [Fred Eduardo](https://answers.ros.org/users/20246/fred-eduardo/) with karma: 31 on 2014-10-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1